# Best way to add controller actions in protected method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

I was told that

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
```

is better handled separately in a protected method. How and why do I need to do so?

Comment: What things? I would move post finding into separate (private or protected) method here.

Comment: @MarekLipka I don’t see any reason to wrap a wrapper :)

Comment: I mean: add @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic should be broken up into methods when it does too many things or is too long.

Looking at your original implementation:

```
  def create
    # refactor into common method since this needs to be done for all actions anyway
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 

    # this chunk is doing two things: comment creation and parameter validation
    # each method should only be responsible for one thing
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

Sample refactor

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # post needs to be set for all actions since this is a nested route
  before_action :set_post 
  # comment only needs to be set for some actions
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]

  def create
    # comment creation belongs within the controller create action
    # param validation should be handled elsewhere
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params # responsible for controlling what params are permitted
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you want to make simple things looking sophisticated, you could try:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    deal_and_redirect do
      @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    end
  end
  def destroy
    deal_and_redirect do
      @post.comments.find(params[:id]).tap { |c| c.destroy }
    end
  end
private
  def deal_and_redirect
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = yield if block_given?
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods shouldn't be private, rather these should always be public. But you can refactor chunk of these methods, and make *them* private like following:

```
before_action :set_post

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

You write that code in `private` methods that is shared between two or more methods. The method `create`, `destroy` should themselves be public, and never private.